# QuickGraph finding indegree of Vertices

Tags: c#, quickgraph

I am using QuickGraph to create a directed acyclic graph. I need to find all vertices whose indegree is zero. I don't see this support on a graph's `Vertices` collection, or a way to filter using LINQ.

Here is a sample data structure I'm composing:

```
var componentGraph = new AdjacencyGraph<Component, Edge<Component>>();

var serverOnMachineA = new TalismaServerComponent("CLTDEPAPI10");
var serverOnMachineB = new TalismaServerComponent("CLTDEPAPI11");
var appServerOnMachineB = new TalismaAppServerComponent("CLTDEPAPI11");
var webComponentsOnMachineC = new TalismaWebComponentsComponent("CLTDEPFE1");

componentGraph.AddVertex(serverOnMachineA);
componentGraph.AddVertex(serverOnMachineB);
componentGraph.AddVertex(appServerOnMachineB);
componentGraph.AddVertex(webComponentsOnMachineC);

componentGraph.AddEdge(new Edge<Component>(appServerOnMachineB, serverOnMachineA));
componentGraph.AddEdge(new Edge<Component>(webComponentsOnMachineC, appServerOnMachineB));
componentGraph.AddEdge(new Edge<Component>(webComponentsOnMachineC, serverOnMachineB));
```

I simply need a list of the vertices in this graph that have no "in" edges (indegree=0).

Comment: Who voted for closing? What is unclear about this question? I vote for leaving open.

Comment: @chiccodoro Thank you! I don't understand why this is unclear either.

Comment: Does `Vertex` have anything like a `IncomingEdges` property or at least something like an `AdjacentEdges` property? Then of course you could filter by using `componentGraph.Vertices.Where(v => !v.IncomingEdges.Any()` or similar. However I reckon you need an implementation of a certain algorithm to make this more performant...

Comment: It has `OutEdges` but not `InEdges`. That's the first thing I looked for.

Comment: I think I found the solution. The guy (or lady) who voted for closing helped you find attention :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need a different graph type. Diving a bit into the forums and source of QuickGraph I found the [BidirectionalGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#3.0/sources/QuickGraph/BidirectionalGraph.cs) class which is

> A mutable directed graph data structure efficient for sparse
>   graph representation where out-edge and in-edges need to be enumerated. Requires
>   twice as much memory as the adjacency graph.

The method to retrieve the in-degree seems to be found on the `IBidirectionalIncidenceGraph` as [this discussion](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/discussions/279323) implies.

The data structure you use does not do book keeping on incoming edges, thus you would have to retrieve the in-degree of a vertex by iterating through all edges and looking at their target, which could be an expensive operation for big graphs.

The `BidirectionalGraph` is quicker for that but takes twice as much memory space for the book-keeping. Using it you could do something like:

```
var orphans = graph.Vertices.Where(v => graph.InDegree(v) == 0)
```

Comment: I think this will work for me! I will only have a handful (<50) vertices, so efficiency is not much of a concern. I will give this a try and mark this as the answer when I have it working. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark, more than glad I could offer help for a question I only found through review :-)

Comment: was that a nice way of telling me to RTFM?

Comment: @Mark it was not the least intended too. I guess I was just lucky to find what you were looking for. I did not know the library but I know the concepts of graphs, indegrees etc.; when I saw that your question still wasn't answered and still was in the review queue I thought I'd rather hasten to help you (and prove that the question was clear enough)